# Unmounts & useState in async callbacks

Tags: reactjs

In React FC's, is fetching directly inside async callbacks an anti-pattern?

Is it okay for the `setState` to be called ***after*** the component unmounts?

```
const Component = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const onClick = e => {
    // What if the component unmounts before setState?
    fetch("url").then(response => response.json()).then(json => setState(json))
  }
  return <button onClick={onClick}></button>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to call an api and fetch data when component mounts then use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

If you want to call it on onClick event, use [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

If component unmounts before setState, it wont break your app but will get an error in console as set state was called in unmounted component.
Optionally to avoid this you can cancel api call when you component unmounts.